# Test class appears in Overall Test Coverage pane in Developer Console

Tags: apex, unit-test

I've written an Apex class that contains `@isTest` above the class declaration.  All of the methods in the class are essentially "test harness" or helper methods that are used by other test scripts.  For some reason, the class appears in the **Overall Test Coverage** pane in Developer Console in my Sandbox, but not in QA.  The class in both environments is identical.  In an effort to resolve this, I tried adding a dummy `testMethod` to this class, but it still appears in the Overall Test Coverage pane for the Sandbox.  Is there a reason why this is happening?

Comment: try to delete and recreate the same class.

Comment: That worked.  Since I referenced that class in other classes, I needed to create a copy and then delete the original.  Definitely a waste of a couple hours of my day.